# CNN learns differently, depending on the way data is provided

Tags: keras

First, I will describe the problem, below, all the necessary code is quoted.
The data I use is correct, I tested it.

So, I have a CNN, that I teach by providing an array of images (let's call it case 1). It learns well.
Then I change the way training data is supplied: I use custom data generator (below) to load images from disk, batch by batch (case 2).

Here is the problem: the second case does not learn at all.
Unless.
Unless I run the first case for a short time, then stop it, and teach the resulting net using second case.
Then it learns as well as the first case was learning.

My understanding is, that the second case misses some important initialization, and by kicking it with first case, I set it right.

Any idea what is missed in a second case?

=== Details

I have a CNN for image classification. Nothing extraordinary:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides = (1, 1), input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1),
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGULARIZER),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(REGULARIZER)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn0'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), name="conv1",
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGULARIZER),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(REGULARIZER)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
model.add(AveragePooling2D((3, 3), name='avg_pool'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu", name='rl',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGULARIZER),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(REGULARIZER)))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
model.add(Dense(train_labels.shape[1], activation='softmax', name='sm',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGULARIZER),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(REGULARIZER)))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Now, it learns nicely, if I feed it with array of images. Images are loaded in a separate function, and an ENTIRE array is provided, so the model breaks it to batches:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2)

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, train_labels, shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=([x_valid[:,:,:, :1]], [valid_labels]), # class_weight=class_weights,
    callbacks=[saveBestModel])
```

The network learns well.
Now, if I load images in batches from the disk, I use the following code:

```
def image_generator(image_file_names, labels):
    while 1:
        total = len(image_file_names)
        for start in range(0, total, BATCH_SIZE):
            x_batch = []
            end = min(start + BATCH_SIZE, total)
            y_batch = labels[start:end, :]
            file_names_batch = image_file_names[start:end]

            text_file = open("log.txt", "a")
            text_file.write("\n".join(file_names_batch))
            text_file.write("\n%s\n===================\n" % start)
            text_file.close()

            for file_name in file_names_batch:
                img = load_img("../input/train/" + file_name,
                target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), grayscale=True)
                img = img_to_array(img)
                #img = datagen.random_transform(img, seed=42)
                img = img / 255.
                x_batch.append(img)
            yield np.array(x_batch), y_batch
```

In this case, the function call is:

```
history = model.fit_generator(image_generator(np_train[:, 0], train_labels), 
    steps_per_epoch=len(np_train) / BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, shuffle=True,
    validation_data=([x_valid[:,:,:, :1]], [valid_labels]), #class_weight=class_weights,
    callbacks=[saveBestModel])
```

Here is the problem: the second case does not learn at all.
Unless.
Unless I run the first case for a short time, then stop it, and teach the resulting net using second case.
Then it learns.

My understanding is, that the second case misses some important initialization, and by kicking it with first case, I set it right.

Any idea what is missed in a second case?

Comment: What happens if you use the first generator and take `BATCH_SIZE` amount of images, put them in the batch and feed that batch to the model?

Comment: Is it equal to calling model.fit_generator with epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=1?

Comment: No, I thought if you can grab a `BATCH_SIZE` amount of elements from the generator and create a batch from that and feed it to the NN as a fixed batch. That way we can see if it's the problem in the preprocessing or something else.

Comment: No effect. And even in model.fit_generator, it takes 2-3 epochs... It seems that the nn of case 2 originally is not learning, and the longer i ran case 1, the better for case 2...